# ON or IN the street/square

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have seen both:

> - *"in the street"* AND *"on the street"*
> - *"in the square"* AND *"on the square"*

Which preposition is correct?

Comment: There isn't a strict rule without context. Any of them might be OK.

Comment: I would never speak of *meeting **on** the square*. Google Books claims about 472 instances of [met **in** Times Square](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22met+in+times+square%22), but [met **on** Times Square](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22met+on+times+square%22) gets only 10 hits (half of which are duplicates anyway).

Comment: @Fumble - _on the square_ is idiomatic English, at least in the US. I seldom hear it used with the name of a particular square (such as Times Square), but I've seen and heard it used plenty. [This magazine article](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2011/02/28/on-the-square-wendell-steavenson) uses the phrase several times – starting in the title, but also in sentences such as, "I met Sherif often on the square," and, "his son and a group of friends had been on the square all day." [More instances in news stories](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22met+on+the+square%22&safe=active&tbm=nws).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36836/discussion-between-j-r-and-fumblefingers).

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions are difficult: there is a lot of flexibility and cultural variation. These are loose guidelines for British english.

If you were talking about a person, **in the street** means that they are standing or walking in the street, Whereas **on the street** means that they are homeless.  Likewise, **in the square** means that they are standing or walking in the square, and **on the square** means that they are honest.

For a vehicle or building you would use **in** for **the** street and **the** square and a named square, eg Times Square, and **in** or **on** for a named street.

Answer (score 0):

If you are

*in the street* you are *"within" the street*.  You are confined within the street.

If you are *on the street* you are talking about the street as a surface.

The same for *square* and other similar places, such as *field*, *playground*.

I'm *in* the square, field, playground = I'm *confined within* the square, field, playground.

I'm *on* the square, field, playground = I'm *on the surface* that is the square, field, playground.

Same for a large mode of transportation: if it's large enough inside to contain a surface you can use *on* to refer to the  inside surface.  Therefore, you can be both *in* (*within*) a bus, train, boat, airplane, elevator or *on* any of these.

Answer (score -2):

**"In the street"** means literally that you are *"in the middle of the street"*, just standing on it

**"On the street"** can be used to describe, for example, buildings, which face the street.

**"The factory was on Jackson Street."**

The same construction can be used in the case of describing a pedestrian who is walking down the street, but he/she is on the sidewalk, not in the middle of the road.